# one date after the other in datetime-local format

Tags: javascript, datetime, input

I want to use datetime-local to input date time for 2 dates. First date   input (id='fd'):

```
<input type="datetime-local" id='fd' name="firstDate">
<script>
var date = new Date(),
fd = document.getElementById('fd');
fd.value = date.toISOString();  
</script>
```

and I want second date (id='sd') input field :

```
<input type="datetime-local" id='sd' name="secondDate">
```

to allow only values (dates) which are after first date (id='fd').Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery maybe could help you out.
You can ignore further actions with this validation.

```
var date = new Date();
var fd = document.getElementById('fd');
fd.value = date.toISOString();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sd').focusout(function() {
    var sdVal = $(this).val();
    if (sdVal > fd.value)
      alert("Dude! I'm bigger than you!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can stll  enter second date as earlier then first date

Answer (score 0):

Listen `change` event of `fd`, and set `min` attribute to `sd`.   We can expect browsers don't allow users to specify earlier dates.  (I found desktop Chrome allows to specify dates earlier than `min` attribute.  So we need to compare valueAsNumber on submit, or enable interactive form validation.)

```
document.querySelector('#fd').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    if (event.target.value.length == 0)
        return;
    // Allow one minute after the first date, or later.
    var min = event.target.valueAsNumber + 60 * 1000;
    var minString = new Date(min).toISOString();
    // Remove ':ss.sssZ'.
    minString = minString.substr(0, minString.length - 8);
    document.querySelector('#sd').min = minString;
}, false);
```

We need to take care of a case where a user specifies a date for `sd` first.